# Laplace Inverse of tan inverse

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

> Obtain inverse Laplace transform of $$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{s^{2}}\right).$$

Here is my work so far:
\begin{align*}
L^{-1}\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{s^{2}}\right)\right]&=f(t)\\
L^{-1}\left[\frac{d}{ds}\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{s^{2}}\right)\right)\right]&=-tf(t)\\
L^{-1}\left[ \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{2}{s^{2}}\right)^{2}}\cdot\left(\frac{-4}{s^{3}}\right)\right]&=-tf(t)\\
L^{-1}\left[\frac{4s}{s^{4}+4}\right]&=tf(t).
\end{align*}

I am unable to proceed after this step.

Comment: Good steps so far. Now you need to do partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: I typeset your question in MathJax, please make sure I interpreted your work correctly, the image you attached was a bit blurry.  You can go to 'edit' to make corrections if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kaynex suggested, noting
$$ s^4+4=(s^4+4s^2+4)-4s^2=(s^2-2s+2)(s^2+2s+2) $$
and
$$ \frac{4s}{s^4+4}=\frac{1}{s^2-2s+2}-\frac{1}{s^2+2s+2}=\frac{1}{(s-1)^2+1}-\frac{1}{(s+1)^2+1} $$
so one has
\begin{eqnarray}
L^{-1}\bigg\{\frac{4s}{s^4+4}\bigg\}&=&L^{-1}\bigg\{\frac{1}{(s-1)^2+1}\bigg\}-L^{-1}\bigg\{\frac{1}{(s+1)^2+1}\bigg\}\\
&=&(e^t-e^{-t})\sin t.
\end{eqnarray}